# VS 2013 - My methods are auto expanded every launch

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

So my methods are auto expanded every launch of `Visual Studio 2013` even when I collapse them before exiting the program.

Is there any thing I can do about this in the settings?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This state is saved in the .suo file. 
Please check the following:
Do you have this file in your solution folder? Is it deleted between different Studio sessions? Is any kind of Source Control involved, with *.suo files being excluded?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. No I don't have this file in my solution explorer and I don't know what source control is so I guess there is no involvement.

Comment: By "solution folder" I meant the directory where you *.sln file is. Try to close your solution, navigate to that folder in Windows Explorer, delete that *.suo file (in case it is corrupted) and repeat your experiment: open solution, open some file in it, collapse some areas, close and reopen.

Comment: I don't have any .sln or .suo in my project folder nor my solution explorer. By "navigate to that folder in Windows Explorer" what do you mean?

Comment: I deleted all my .sln files of my project  and now I can't open my project |:

Comment: Actually it worked but I don't have the original VS launcher. Its kinda weird but whatever, That's another stackoverflow question. Thank you.

Comment: Hmm... I suggested to delete the auto-generated *.suo file, NOT the solution (*.sln) file itself!

Comment: You can create an empty solution and add your projects to it. You didn't delete the projects files (*.vcxproj), did you?

Comment: I didn't delete the *.vcxproj files. But I have a copy of the project before I deleted the .sln files. Lets do it right this time. I need to go to the solution folder and delete **ALL** the *.suo files? Thanks.